Magento2 Admin logs out when going to Sales Order ot Content Configuration
When I go to Sales Order or Content Configuration,it logs out the admin. My Magento version is 2.3.7-p4.

I have already increased the session.gc_maxlifetime

Please run the below command in SSH and check
php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 256000

Let me know if I can help you more with anything related the issue, Thank You!

You don't need to write the asker's name in every answer. Please leave it out. Thank you.
